# How to dynamically add and remove views between two Views

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsview

I'm working on a cocoa app, in which i wanted to dynamically add, remove, resize views.
[image]
Shown above is the image, in which there are three views in a parent view out of which view-B can be added or removed and based on that we need to resize view-C.

Any cocoa/objective-c help for this.

Comment: Try `addSubview`/`removeFromSuperview` and re-calculate the sizes for each. I have not worked with constraints. They might ease the job.

Comment: You should consider using [`NSStackView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSStackView_Class/index.html) for this sort of UI, if you can require OS X 10.9 or later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//To add a subview
[parentView addSubview:subview];

//To remove a subview
[subview removeFromSuperview];

//To resize a view
[subview setFrameSize: NSMakeSize(width, height)];
[subview setFrameOrigin: NSMakePoint(originX, originY)];
```

If you need to set the frame of a view based on the size or position of other views, you can use a views frame which has a size and an origin etc...

For example, to move C so it borders A and takes up the rest of the space in the view:

```
NSSize size = NSMakeSize(parentView.frame.size.width, parentView.frame.size.height - a.frame.size.height);
NSPoint origin = NSMakePoint(a.frame.origin.x, a.frame.origin.y + a.frame.size.height);

[c setFrameSize: size];
[c setFrameOrigin: origin];
```